# VBA excel combobox shapes select

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

i have problem with selecting combobox after creating it via shapes object. Can someone please help?

My code is

```
Dim comboBoxRange As Range
Set comboBoxRange = Sheets(axleDataWindowName).Range("F2:F4")
currentSheet.DropDowns.Add(20, 40, 100, 15).Name = "modifiedComboBox"
With currentSheet.Shapes("modifiedComboBox")
    .Left = 450
    .List comboBoxRange.Value
End With
```

Comment: Do you want **.List** or **.ListFillRange** ?

Comment: Im not sure in difference between this two options

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `currentSheet.Dropdowns("modifiedComboBox")` instead of `currentSheet.Shapes("modifiedComboBox")`. Also use `.AddItem` instead of `.List`:

```
Dim comboBoxRange As Range
Set comboBoxRange = Sheets(axleDataWindowName).Range("F2:F4")
currentSheet.DropDowns.Add(20, 40, 100, 15).Name = "modifiedComboBox"
With currentSheet.Shapes("modifiedComboBox")
    .Left = 450
    .AddItem comboBoxRange.Value
End With
```